# Progress bar should display on screen until web page loads fully

Tags: jquery, load, progress-bar, page-load-time

I am using bellow code to display progress bar.

```
jQuery('#container').showLoading(
{
      'afterShow':
       function () 
       {
          setTimeout("jQuery('#container').hideLoading()", 1000);
       }
});
```

Progress bar displays on screen till `1000` milliseconds and then disappear.
But I want that progress bar display on screen till  `(time) = page load`. 
means statically I am taking 1000 milliseconds but I want progress bar display that much time .. that a page take time to load.

So how to get page load time and pass it here ??

Comment: Preloading techniques aside, you can have a look here for a  solution... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13182282/how-to-find-out-what-percentage-of-the-page-has-loaded-in-order-to-update-the-jq

Answer (score 2):

What we need to do is first show the progress indicator as soon as we are able to and then, when the page is fully loaded, hide it. We can do this by binding a load event to the window object when the DOM is ready.

**Please Note:** On a page this small, you may not notice the loader because it will all happen too quickly.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  showHideLoading(); // load this func as soon as the doc is ready

});

function showHideLoading() {

  // We'll be referencing #loader more than once so let's cache it
  var loader = jQuery("#loader");

  // now we'll show the #loader
  loader.show();

  // We'll set up a new event so that when everything on the page
  // has finished loading, we hide our #loader
  jQuery(window).on("load", function() {
    loader.fadeOut(500);
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  }
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  /*this is only here to make the page load a little more slowly */
}
#loader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

}
#loader div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: -40px 0 0 -75px;
  background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 80px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- this is only here to make the page load a little more slowly -->
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/cats-q-c-1920-1080-8.jpg" />


<div id="loader">

  <div>Loading</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't get the page load time, however you can bind to `window.onload` event to hide the progress bar. `window.onload` event will fire only when the page is completely loaded.

```
        window.onload = function() {
            jQuery('#container').hideLoading();
        };
```

Comment: Ohk. Then where do I place window.onload .. inside $(document ).ready(). or before it? @maheshsapkal

Comment: I have tried it. But no effects. I have to get page load time and pass it in place of 1000 milliseconds.

Comment: But you can't get the page load time before the page has loaded, and the page load time will be dependent on many factors, bandwidth, latency, browser, cell coverage, speed of browsers JS engine etc.